# onClick event of textview does not happening

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I can`t understand why my onClick event of textview does not happening?
My code:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{    
Context my_ctx;
private static CountDownTimer countDownTimer;   
private static Toast my_toast;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    my_ctx = context;
    showing_toast("Message");
}

public void showing_toast(String Message)
{       
my_toast  = Toast.makeText(my_ctx, Message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    TextView textView = new TextView(my_ctx);
    textView.setText(Message);  

    textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
                countDownTimer.cancel();                                                 
         }
        });

    my_toast.setView(textView);

    countDownTimer  = new CountDownTimer((30)*1000, 1000) {
          @Override
          public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            my_toast.show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {                
            my_toast.cancel();
        }
    }.start();  

}
```

So, countDownTimer go on and toast message doesn`t disappear although i click on textview

Comment: i think you need make textview  clickable in its properties

Comment: already set. See above "textView.setOnClickListener(...);"

Comment: try adding `textView.setClickable(true);` before "textView.setOnClickListener(...);"

Comment: it doesn`t help... you know, I find a similar question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398402/android-overlay-layout-on-top-of-all-windows-that-receives-touches?answertab=votes#tab-top). @akos-cz advises to use View.setFilterTouchesWhenObscured(Boolean) method (but i don`t know how) because framework being filtering touch events to prevent "click jacking" exploits.